# How to remove armature in NLA editor?

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

[image: How to delete these 2 "EYE Right" and Hands Left" in the NLA editor. I don' tknow how i got them there in the first place]

How can i remove those 2 armatures in my NLA editor?

Comment: Do you want to *remove* remove the armatures, or just hide them from the NLA?

Comment: I just wanted to get rid of the two in the NLA editor.

Comment: Remove the respective armatures in the 3D viewport.